# in postgres, how do you call a prepared statement from within a procedure

Tags: database, postgresql, prepared-statement

in postgres

- as an SQL command [`execute`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-execute.html) runs a prepared statement
- from within a procedure [`execute`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) runs a dynamic command.

can prepared statements be called from within a procedure?

---

per Frank below, part of code to insert a user into an arbitrary schema:

```
  execute 'insert into '||v_schema||'.usr( login, email, name, role, pwd ) 
      values( $1, $2, $3, $4, md5($5) )
      returning usr_id'
      into v_usr_id
      using p_login, p_email, p_name, v_role, p_pwd;
```

notes:

- INTO clause *before* USING clause
- no parens around USING "args"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [EXECUTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in combination with USING (available since version 8.4):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(int) 
RETURNS bool
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO tablename(columnname) VALUES($1);' USING($1); -- your input

    RETURN true;
END;
$$;
```